# SQL WHERE NOT...IN vs WHERE ... NOT IN

Tags: mysql, sql, notin

Is there any difference or best practices between the following two statements, syntax, performance, style, or otherwise?

```
SELECT TitleOfCourtesy, FirstName, LastName
FROM Employees
WHERE NOT TitleOfCourtesy IN ('Ms.','Mrs.');



SELECT TitleOfCourtesy, FirstName, LastName
FROM Employees
WHERE TitleOfCourtesy NOT IN ('Ms.','Mrs.');
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the underlying query execution is the same for both. It's just a matter of preference. Personally, WHERE column NOT IN sounds more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the `Where... NOT IN` is the one I've come across the most and in terms of the industry it is preferred in order to make the statement more readable for others who aren't accustomed to seeing `Where NOT ... IN`.